# How to iterate between all enumerations in an enumeration

Tags: swift, enums, enumeration

Let's suppose i have some kind of enum - "A", which have 3 more enums in it - "B","C","D"
So it will look like this

```
enum A  {
    enum B {
    }
    enum C {
    }
    enum D {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate thought B,C,D, like i've iterate throught `case` values?

**EDIT**

I want to get all the enums from A, like i've get all the enumerators from B,C,D, to use them in a cycle

Comment: Can i ask why you have enums inside an enum?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri mostly because of the structure
I access values from B enum with `A.B.VALUE`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"iterate between all enumerations"_? What is you're expected result? Can you give a real world example? Please [edit] your question and add more detail.

Comment: Ok. I will rephrase. Why do you want to access it as `A.B.VALUE`

Comment: I think it is not possible and may be you are in wrong direction

Comment: @RakeshaShastri In my code, A is a general identifier, B,C,D are some kind of children, what are generated mostly randomly, and then, after the child was generated, i want to access all it's values

Comment: I think you should share the actual problem you have as it is.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's possible... Only if you're ok with `Any`

`A.B`, `A.C`, and `A.D` are all completely different types.
To group them all in an Array will mean that it will be of type: `[Any]`

```swift
enum A {
    enum B: CaseIterable { case foo, bar }
    enum C: CaseIterable { case foo, bar }
    enum D: CaseIterable { case foo, bar }

    // Here is what I added. It's familiar to `allCases` from the `CaseIterable` protocol
    static var allRecursiveEnumCases: [Any] { B.allCases + C.allCases + D.allCases }
}
```

Let's try to access them!
The only way to do so is through down casting:

```swift
for i in A.allRecursiveEnumCases {
    if let enumB = i as? A.B {
        print("A.B.\(enumB)")
    } else if let enumC = i as? A.C {
        print("A.C.\(enumC)")
    } else if let enumD = i as? A.D {
        print("A.D.\(enumD)")
    }
}

// Output:
// A.B.foo
// A.B.bar
// A.C.foo
// A.C.bar
// A.D.foo
// A.D.bar
```

Answer (score -3):

```
enum A: CaseIterable  {
    enum B {
    }
    enum C {
    }
    enum D {
    }
}
for obj in A.AllCases() {
print(obj)
}
```

Comment: This iterates through the all the cases of an enum. This is not the question the OP is asking.